# How to solve Undefined index: language in SMARTY framework

Tags: php, phpstorm, smarty

[image]

When I run the project I get an error saying:

> Undefined index: language.

If anyone knows the answer please help!
thanks.

Comment: There is no key: language, check your array.

Comment: array(2) { ["module"]=> string(7) "Install" ["view"]=> string(5) "Index" }this is the array ! do you know how to fix it